# Jagged Array VB.NET

Tags: arrays, vb.net, visual-studio-2015, aes

I'm trying to use jagged arrays to build an AES encryption tool. It is purely to help me get my head around the maths of the encryption, not for any real application. I tried using 2D arrays but just could not figure out how to iterate through them properly; so I looked into jagged arrays. I can declare and initialize the ones where data is constant and won't change; but I'm also trying to iterate through one to add data to it, but I get error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when trying to add to a jagged array. Here is my code

```
Imports System.Text

Public Class Form1

    Dim sBox()() As String = {({"63", "7C", "77", "7B", "F2", "6B", "6F", "C5", "30", "01", "67", "2B", "FE", "D7", "AB", "76"}),
({"CA", "82", "C9", "7D", "FA", "59", "47", "F0", "AD", "D4", "A2", "AF", "9C", "A4", "72", "C0"}),
({"B7", "FD", "93", "26", "36", "3F", "F7", "CC", "34", "A5", "E5", "F1", "71", "D8", "31", "15"}),
({"04", "C7", "23", "C3", "18", "96", "05", "9A", "07", "12", "80", "E2", "EB", "27", "B2", "75"}),
({"09", "83", "2C", "1A", "1B", "6E", "5A", "A0", "52", "3B", "D6", "B3", "29", "E3", "2F", "84"}),
({"53", "D1", "00", "ED", "20", "FC", "B1", "5B", "6A", "CB", "BE", "39", "4A", "4C", "58", "CF"}),
({"D0", "EF", "AA", "FB", "43", "4D", "33", "85", "45", "F9", "02", "7F", "50", "3C", "9F", "A8"}),
({"51", "A3", "40", "8F", "92", "9D", "38", "F5", "BC", "B6", "DA", "21", "10", "FF", "F3", "D2"}),
({"CD", "0C", "13", "EC", "5F", "97", "44", "17", "C4", "A7", "7E", "3D", "64", "5D", "19", "73"}),
({"60", "81", "4F", "DC", "22", "2A", "90", "88", "46", "EE", "B8", "14", "DE", "5E", "0B", "DB"}),
({"E0", "32", "3A", "0A", "49", "06", "24", "5C", "C2", "D3", "AC", "62", "91", "95", "E4", "79"}),
({"E7", "C8", "37", "6D", "8D", "D5", "4E", "A9", "6C", "56", "F4", "EA", "65", "7A", "AE", "08"}),
({"BA", "78", "25", "2E", "1C", "A6", "B4", "C6", "E8", "DD", "74", "1F", "4B", "BD", "8B", "8A"}),
({"70", "3E", "B5", "66", "48", "03", "F6", "0E", "61", "35", "57", "B9", "86", "C1", "1D", "9E"}),
({"E1", "F8", "98", "11", "69", "D9", "8E", "94", "9B", "1E", "87", "E9", "CE", "55", "28", "DF"}),
({"8C", "A1", "89", "0D", "BF", "E6", "42", "68", "41", "99", "2D", "0F", "B0", "54", "BB", "16"})}
    Dim invSBox()() As String = {({"52", "09", "6A", "D5", "30", "36", "A5", "38", "BF", "40", "A3", "9E", "81", "F3", "D7", "FB"}),
({"7C", "E3", "39", "82", "9B", "2F", "FF", "87", "34", "8E", "43", "44", "C4", "DE", "E9", "CB"}),
({"54", "7B", "94", "32", "A6", "C2", "23", "3D", "EE", "4C", "95", "0B", "42", "FA", "C3", "4E"}),
({"08", "2E", "A1", "66", "28", "D9", "24", "B2", "76", "5B", "A2", "49", "6D", "8B", "D1", "25"}),
({"72", "F8", "F6", "64", "86", "68", "98", "16", "D4", "A4", "5C", "CC", "5D", "65", "B6", "92"}),
({"6C", "70", "48", "50", "FD", "ED", "B9", "DA", "5E", "15", "46", "57", "A7", "8D", "9D", "84"}),
({"90", "D8", "AB", "00", "8C", "BC", "D3", "0A", "F7", "E4", "58", "05", "B8", "B3", "45", "06"}),
({"D0", "2C", "1E", "8F", "CA", "3F", "0F", "02", "C1", "AF", "BD", "03", "01", "13", "8A", "6B"}),
({"3A", "91", "11", "41", "4F", "67", "DC", "EA", "97", "F2", "CF", "CE", "F0", "B4", "E6", "73"}),
({"96", "AC", "74", "22", "E7", "AD", "35", "85", "E2", "F9", "37", "E8", "1C", "75", "DF", "6E"}),
({"47", "F1", "1A", "71", "1D", "29", "C5", "89", "6F", "B7", "62", "0E", "AA", "18", "BE", "1B"}),
({"FC", "56", "3E", "4B", "C6", "D2", "79", "20", "9A", "DB", "C0", "FE", "78", "CD", "5A", "F4"}),
({"1F", "DD", "A8", "33", "88", "07", "C7", "31", "B1", "12", "10", "59", "27", "80", "EC", "5F"}),
({"60", "51", "7F", "A9", "19", "B5", "4A", "0D", "2D", "E5", "7A", "9F", "93", "C9", "9C", "EF"}),
({"A0", "E0", "3B", "4D", "AE", "2A", "F5", "B0", "C8", "EB", "BB", "3C", "83", "53", "99", "61"}),
({"17", "2B", "04", "7E", "BA", "77", "D6", "26", "E1", "69", "14", "63", "55", "21", "0C", "7D"})}
    Dim rci()() As String = {({"01", "02", "04", "08", "10", "20", "40", "80", "1B", "36"})}
    Dim cipherKey As String
    Dim newKey As New StringBuilder
    Dim istate()() As String
    Dim strVal As String
    Dim rnd As New Random
    Dim column As Integer
    Dim row As Integer

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        cipherKey = TextBox1.Text
        newKey.Clear()

        For i = 0 To 3
            For x = 0 To 3

                For Each c As Char In cipherKey
                    strVal = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(c), 16)

                    istate(i)(x) = strVal
                Next
            Next
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

I am receiving the error on the line `istate(i)(x) = strVal`

I appreciate that my code may not be efficient, like I say I am simply just trying to build it and programme each element of AES to get a better understanding of how it works and the maths

Comment: You can't add to a jagged array or any array for that matter. Arrays are fixed size.  All you can do is set elements that already exist. Of course that line throws a `NullReferenceException`, because you haven't created any arrays. There are no elements to set.  Learn how arrays in general work first, then extend the same principles to multidimensional and/or jagged arrays.

Comment: if you need to add...consider a list of lists...or an array of lists if the first dimension is fixed

Answer (score 0):

ALL arrays are fixed-size, be they one-dimensional, multi-dimensional or jagged.  If you do this:

```
Dim istate As String()
```

Then you have not created an array.  You have simply declared a variable that can refer to an array.  If you have not specified the size of the array, either implicitly or explicitly, then you have no created an array.  That means that any attempt to index an array via that variable will fail, because there is no array.  In order to create an array of a particular size, you have to specify the upper bound, e.g.

```
Dim istate(3) As String
```

Now the variable refers to an array object with four elements, so you can access those elements by index.  For a 2D array, you have to specify the upper bound for both dimensions, e.g.

```
Dim istate(3, 3) As String
```

Now you have an array with four by four elements and you can access each one by indexes.  A jagged array is a 1D array of 1D arrays, so you can only initially specify the size of the outer array, i.e. how many 1D arrays that 1D array will contain, e.g.

```
Dim istate(3)() As String
```

You then have to create each inner array, e.g.

```
For i = 0 To istate.GetUpperBound(0)
    istate(i) = New String(3) {}
Next
```

Now you can access each element of each inner array by indexes.

Arrays are reference-type objects so array variables act just like any other reference-type variables, i.e. objects don't appear out of thin air. You have to create them.